# Increment in specific elements of vector in R

Tags: r, vector

In R language I have a vector v<-c(1,2,3,4). I want to increment only one of these elements if some condition is satisfied. For Example, if the condition is fulfilled then I want to add 1 in the first element only, keeping the remaining elements as same then v should be v<-c(2,2,3,4). Any idea?

Comment: `if (Condition) v[1] <- v[1] + 1`

Comment: It worked. Thanks @jogo

Comment: Please check this link for the related question on above problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996180/changing-vector-elements-according-to-if-condition @jogo