# Changing vector elements according to if condition

Tags: r, vector

I have pos as matrix of array indices that has 24 rows and 2 columns. In first column it contains the values 1,2,3,4.

```
$position
      row col
 [1,]   4   6
 [2,]   1   6
 [3,]   4   5
 [4,]   2   6
 [5,]   1   5
 [6,]   3   6
 [7,]   4   4
 [8,]   2   5
 [9,]   1   4
[10,]   3   5
[11,]   2   4
[12,]   4   3
[13,]   1   3
[14,]   3   4
[15,]   2   3
[16,]   4   2
[17,]   3   3
[18,]   1   2
[19,]   2   2
[20,]   3   2
[21,]   4   1
[22,]   1   1
[23,]   2   1
[24,]   3   1
```

I tried the code

```
ch<-c(5,7,10,5)
C<-150
s<-c(1,1,1,1); s
cost<-sum(ch*s)
repeat
{
for(i in 1:24)
{
  for (j in 1:4)
  {
if (pos[i,1]==j) s[j]<-s[j]+1 else s
  }
  if (cost<C)
  {
    break
  }
}
}
s
```

Here s returns s=c(1,1,1,4280236) but the result should be s=c(5,6,6,5)

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: As pos [24,] shows 3rd row index s should be s=c(1,1,"2",1) 
pos[23,] shows 2nd row index s should become s=c(1,"2",2,1)
pos [22,] shows 1st row index now s should be s=c("2",2,2,1)
Similarly For pos[21,] s=c(2,2,2,"2")
For pos[20,] s=c(2,2,"3",2)
For pos[19,] s=c(2,"3",3,2) and so on. Inverted commas just represent the changed element acoording to row index in pos.@RalfStubner

Comment: Unclear. Please explain what you need to do

Comment: I want to Pick the largest value in the array that has not already been picked; associate
it with its row; ( This result is stored in ‘pos’ matrix here ) and increase that row sample size (s<-c(1,1,1,1)) by 1 if the new cost including this 1 new unit is ch*s<C. Otherwise (i.e ch*s>C) stop without increasing the sample size by 1 for the associated row. @Sotos

Comment: Running your code: the repeat-loop will not stop. In the inner for-loop the part `else s` is doing nothing. (beside: in the then-branch you have an operation for an element of a vector and in the else-branch you are using a complete vector). Why don't you have to recalculate `cost` in the loop?

Comment: operation for an element of the vector changes the complete ‘s’ vector and cost should be recalculated each time before the operation for an element of the vector.  Secondly, I’m not asking to write the code. I am new to R language but have written the code. Just point out where I am wrong as I am not getting the desired result from this code @jogo

Comment: Your objects `cost` and `C` are set only at the begin of the code. They leave unchanged during the rest. Your condition for the **break** is always TRUE (27 < 150), but it breaks only the for-loop (read the documentation). So the repeat-loop has no exit. How you get the result `s=c(1,1,1,4280236)`? Please put the output from `dput(pos)` in your question.

Comment: I changed the code in light of your comments and got the desired results 
   ' for(i in 24:1)
{
  for(j in 1:4)
  {
    if (pos[i,1]==j) s[j]<-s[j]+1 
  }
  cost<-sum(ch*s)
  if (cost>=C) break
}
s; cost ' resulting in s=c(5,6,6,5), cost=152. Thanks for the response @jogo

Comment: Done @jogo. Your guidance is appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pos <- structure(c(4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
    6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(24L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", "col")))
ch <- c(5,7,10,5)
C <- 150
s <- c(1,1,1,1)
for (i in 24:1) {
  # for(j in 1:4)
  # {
  #   if (pos[i,1]==j) s[j] <- s[j]+1  
  # }
  j <- pos[i,1]; s[j] <- s[j]+1
  cost <- sum(ch*s)
  if (cost>=C) break
}
s; cost
```

As a variant one can run through the first column of the matrix `pos`

```
for (j in pos[24:1, "row"]) {
  s[j] <- s[j]+1  
  cost <- sum(ch*s)
  if (cost>=C) break
}
s; cost
```